# cythonize under py3.6.4 Cannot convert 'basestring' object to bytes implicitly. This is not portable

Tags: cython, cythonize

This code snippet works just fine under python 3.6.4 but is triggering a portability issue when present in .pyx files. I could use some help figuring out how to best format python 3.5.1+ bytes in Cython.

EDIT: Changing this in light of DavidW's comment.

Following works in python 3.6.4 under ipython

```
def py_foo():
    bytes_1 = b'bytes 1'
    bytes_2 = b'bytes 2'

    return b'%(bytes_1)b %(bytes_2)b' % {
                    b'bytes_1': bytes_1,
                    b'bytes_2': bytes_2}
```

As hoped this results in:

```
print(py_foo())

b'bytes 1 bytes 2'
```

Using cython with the only changes to the code being the name of the function, a return type declared, and declaring the two variables.

```
%load_ext Cython
# Cython==0.28
```

followed by:

```
%%cython
cpdef bytes cy_foo():
    cdef:
        bytes bytes_1, bytes_2

    bytes_1 = b'bytes 1'
    bytes_2 = b'bytes 2'

    return b'%(bytes_1)b %(bytes_2)b' % {
                    b'bytes_1': bytes_1,
                    b'bytes_2': bytes_2}
```

Results in:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
....
    return b'%(bytes_1)b %(bytes_2)b' % {
                                     ^
..._cython_magic_b0aa5be86bdfdf75b98df1af1a2394af.pyx:7:38: Cannot convert 'basestring' object to bytes implicitly. This is not portable.
```

-djv

Comment: As it is I get `undeclared name not builtin: binascii`. If I import the standard library module to fix this then it works fine for me with Python 3.6.4 and Cython 0.27.3. Could you make sure this is actually an [mcve]? (Cython version is possibly the main information missing)

Comment: DavidW thanks for checking. I will have to work at that since the original source this comes out of is fairly large. Cython version was 0.28. I will work up a minimal .pxd and .pyx that duplicate this if I can.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a useful answer or just a more detailed diagnosis, but: the issue is with the return type. If you do:

```
cpdef cy_foo1(): # no return type specified
    # everything else exactly the same
```

then it's happy. If you do

```
cpdef bytes cy_foo2():
    # everything else the same
    return bytes(b'%(bytes_1)b %(bytes_2)b' % {
                b'bytes_1': bytes_1,
                b'bytes_2': bytes_2})
```

then it's happy. If you do

```
def mystery_function_that_returns_not_bytes():
    return 1

cpdef bytes cy_foo3():
    return mystery_function_that_returns_not_bytes()
```

then it compiles happily but gives a runtime exception (as you would expect)

---

The issue seems to be that it knows `bytes % something` returns a `basestring` but it isn't confident that it returns `bytes` and isn't prepared to leave it until runtime to try (unlike the cases where it's totally sure, or completely unsure, when it will leave it until runtime).

The above examples show a couple of ways of working round it. Personally, I'd just remove the return type - you don't get a lot of benefit from typing Python objects such as `bytes` anyway. You should probably also report this as a bug to https://github.com/cython/cython/issues